# how do I debug the formatting of a flutter app?

Tags: flutter

The background to my problem is that I have an AppBar, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to change the text colour from black.

So, coming from a webdev background, I want to reach for the devconsole, click on the offending element and see the cascading styles that resulted in the text being black.

My question is, what is the Flutter equivalent of this debugging process?

Comment: You can use Widget-inspector for this color issue case